# I have a problem with Unity making a graphic.Raycaster

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Hello fellow internet users,

In my game i'm trying to use the graphic.Raycaster so that I can signal a piece of the UI, or an item, that I wan't to pick it up. The problem is, I don't get much further then shooting the raycast that hits absolutely nothing. In the script, which I have given down below, it only reaches Debug.Log("test 2");, and no further, stating that it hits nothing. How do I make it actually hit something? If there is anymore information that you need, please let me know.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;

public class InventoryCanvasTestScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GraphicRaycaster m_Raycaster;
    public PointerEventData m_PointerEventData;
    public EventSystem m_EventSystem;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        //Fetch the Raycaster from the GameObject (the Canvas)
        m_Raycaster = GetComponent<GraphicRaycaster>();
        //Fetch the Event System from the Scene
        m_EventSystem = GetComponent<EventSystem>();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (InventoryManager.IsInventoryOpen == true)
        {
            //Debug.Log("test 0");

            //Check if the left Mouse button is clicked
            if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Mouse0))
            {
                //Debug.Log("test 1");
                //Set up the new Pointer Event
                m_PointerEventData = new PointerEventData(m_EventSystem);
                //Set the Pointer Event Position to that of the mouse position
                m_PointerEventData.position = Input.mousePosition;

                //Create a list of Raycast Results
                List<RaycastResult> results = new List<RaycastResult>();


                //Raycast using the Graphics Raycaster and mouse click position
                m_Raycaster.Raycast(m_PointerEventData, results);

                //Debug.Log("test 2");

                //For every result returned, output the name of the GameObject on the Canvas hit by the Ray
                foreach (RaycastResult result in results)
                {
                    Debug.Log("test 3");
                    Debug.Log("Hit " + result.gameObject.name);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I did get this warning too in my console. I don't know if it'll help.:

Should not be capturing when there is a hotcontrol
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent (int,intptr,bool&)

I did check if it was connected to an eventsystem in my hierarchy, which it is. I did check if it was attached to my canvas, which it is. I did check if it had an Graphic Raycaster, which it does.

I also tried to attach a 2D box Collider to my items, which are small images by the way, but that did nothing either. And yes, "Is Trigger" is turned on. They also got a canvas component on just to be sure, bot nothing changed.

Comment: what speaks against just using the raycasts the EventSystem already fires against UI anyway (causing hover and press effects and triggers etc)?

Comment: I can't seem to find any information regarding EventSystem already shooting Raycasts, could you maybe help me with some sources?

Comment: all the UI things like `Button`, `ScrollRect`, `Toggle`, etc already implement interfaces `IPointerXYHandler` (where XY is `Enter`, `Exit`, `Down`, `Up`, `Click`, etc) which the default `EventSystem` which is automatically created next to your `Canvas` already uses through the mentioned `GraphicsRaycaster` attached to the `Canvas` ... so the question is why not simply use the built-in UI components or alternatively implement the [`IPointerXYHandler`](https://docs.unity3d.com/2019.1/Documentation/ScriptReference/EventSystems.IPointerEnterHandler.html) interfaces yourself?

Comment: thank you for your answer. I will try to come up with a solution, and if I end up with more problems, I will make sure to reach out to you. May you resume a good day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use built-in UI functionality. The canvas already has graphics raycaster on it, so just pile on your inventory with items as buttons or as custom elements with `IPointerDownHandler` or similar interface in your script, and have fun. There is tons of official and unofficial tutorials on Unity Learn and YouTube, as well as everywhere on the Internet. From what I've got from your question, the goal is pretty simple and you don't need any custom raycasting or event handling functionality besides what Unity is already giving yo you.

Comment: I'll try another solution through the use of UI buttons, but I already tried once, and came into problems since the buttons only send out a signal once, and not repeatedly. I also had a problem with ways to interact with the button, as if i want e.g. be able to do more than just left click. You know, the typical left click to move, and right click to get a menu with different options. That wouldn't seem to work either. I therefore gave up on that, and tried something "new" that could maybe work, and here I am trying to make a graphic.Raycaster.

Comment: Don't invent what is invented. Create a custom MonoBehaviour, implement `IPointerClickHandler` interface and you'll get a click event with button index as a parameter, see here for API: https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.ugui@1.0/api/UnityEngine.EventSystems.IPointerClickHandler.html . Just slap some Image to your game object so it will be a raycast target under the Canvas hierarchy.

Comment: thank you for your answer. I will try to come up with a solution, and if I end up with more problems, I will make sure to reach out to you. May you resume a good day.